# accessing and removing objects by ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have certain requirements , I wanted to do the following in quickest way as possible.

1. I have 1000's of objects like below
   `{id:1,value:"value1"}  . . {id:1000,value:"value1000"}`
2. I want to access above objects by id
3. I want to clean the objects Lesser than certain id  every few minutes  (Because it generates 1000's of objects every second for my high frequency algorithm)

I can clean easily by using this.

```
 myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.id > cleanSize;
    });
```

I can find the object by id using

```
   myArray.find(x => x.id === '45');
```

Problem is here , I feel that find is little slower when there is larger sets of data.So I created some objects of object like below

```
  const id = 22;
  myArray["x" + id] = {};
  myArray["x" + id] = { id: id, value:"test" };
```

so I can access my item by id easily by myArray[x22]; , but problem is i am not able find the way to remove older items by id.

someone guide me better way to achieve the three points I mentioned above using arrays or objects.

Comment: A _"feeling"_ is never a good estimate of performance...

Comment: When you make the index object, you don't need the "x". You can use the numeric id as a property name (well, it'll be treated as a string).

Comment: `.filter()` and `.find()` accomplish two totally different things. If you want to get rid of (more than) one element use `.filter()`. If you want to modify one element in your array then use `.find()`. If you want to remove one specific element from an array then use `.findIndex()` and `.splice()`, ...

Comment: @Andreas , I need both, I need to find 1 element and every couple of minutes wants to fillter and remove older objects which i dont need anymore.

Comment: So then what's the problem? _"every couple of minutes"_ some milliseconds spend in `.find()` is nothing I would worry about.

Comment: @Pointy : thanks , can I use that string property to remove items < n

Comment: @Andreas : I am sorry , I confused you I guess , every 1 second I will be running 100's of find and every couple minutes I will be deleting older objects using filter.

Comment: Why don't you use a circular buffer instead? That would remove any need to cleanup your old objects, and automatically adapt the size of the storage to your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with your question is, you're asking for a way to finish an algorithm that is supposed to solve a problem of yours, but I think there's something fundamentally wrong with the problem to begin with :)

If you store a sizeable amount of data records, each associated with an ID, and allow your code to access them freely, then you cannot have another part of your code dump some of them to the bin out of the blue (say, from within some timer callback) just because they are becoming "too old". You must be sure nobody is still working on them (and will ever need to) before deleting any of them.

If you don't explicitly synchronize the creation and deletion of your records, you might end up with a code that happens to work (because your objects happen to be processed quickly enough never to be deleted too early), but will be likely to break anytime (if your processing time increases and your data becomes "too old" before being fully processed).

This is especially true in the context of a browser. Your code is supposed to run on any computer connected to the Internet, which could have dozens of reasons to be running 10 or 100 times slower than the machine you test your code on. So making assumptions about the processing time of thousands of records is asking for serious trouble.

Without further specification, it seems to me answering your question would be like helping you finish a gun that would only allow you to shoot yourself in the foot :)

All this being said, any JavaScript object inherently does exactly what you ask for, provided you're okay with using strings for IDs, since an object property name can also be used as an index in an associative array.

```js
var associative_array = {}
var bob = { id:1456, name:"Bob" }
var ted = { id:2375, name:"Ted" }

// store some data with arbitrary ids
associative_array[bob.id] = bob
associative_array[ted.id] = ted
console.log(JSON.stringify(associative_array)) // Bob and Ted

// access data by id
var some_guy = associative_array[2375] // index will be converted to string anyway
console.log(JSON.stringify(some_guy)) // Ted
var some_other_guy = associative_array["1456"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(some_other_guy)) // Bob
var some_AWOL_guy = associative_array[9999]
console.log(JSON.stringify(some_AWOL_guy)) // undefined

// delete data by id
delete associative_array[bob.id] // so long, Bob
console.log(JSON.stringify(associative_array)) // only Ted left
```

Though I doubt speed will really be an issue, this mechanism is about as fast as you will ever get JavaScript to run, since the underlying data structure is a hash table, theoretically O(1).

Anything involving array methods like `find()` or `filter()` will run in at least O(n).
Besides, each invocation of `filter()` would waste memory and CPU recreating the array to no avail.